# Is there a way to get name of argument used in the call of a function in c

Tags: c, function, arguments

I am trying in C to get the name of the variable used when the call to the function was made, as below:

```
func(varA, varB)
```

I would like to know the names of the arguments `(varA, varB)`

I am printing the contents of several matrices, and I was wonderign if there is any easy way to distinguish between them without having to actually send the name as a string.

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to know them for? For debugging? Run your code in a debugger and you'll know. Besides, the arguments need not have names. What if the function was called with `func(n + 1, next())`?

Comment: Hi. @DCuser If any answer has solved your problem please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without changing the function definition.

You can pass the names manually or use a macro:

```
#define func( a , b )    func2( a , b , #a , #b )

func2( type a , type b , const char* namea , const char* nameb ){ ...
```

When preprocessing the code, operator # will transform the variable into a string.

Answer (score 1):

When a C program is compiled and being executed, there is basically no existence of the *variable name* anymore.

So, no, there is not way you can get an actual argument's (variable) *name* from the received parameter, as you wanted.